# Specifying path for WEB-INF in Tomcat container in an Azure "App Service"

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-webapps

web.xml contains the path for WEB-INF. This is how it looks on my local computer:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>webInfPath</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\\eclipse workspace\\...\\MyProject\\WEB-INF</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I deployed my Java/JSP application to a Tomcat container in an Azure "App Service".

I need to specify the new path of WEB-INF in web.xml to reflect the deployment path.

How do I do this?

I have tried doing `<%=servletContext.getRealPath("/")%>` in a jsp to retrieve the filepath, but this fails due to not recognizing servletContext as a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, The WEB-INF floder is under D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT in Azurer web app. The detailed steps are as below.

1. Get Kudo

[image]
2.Get Path
[image]